# PHPmailer: attaching a session variable to an email

Tags: email, pdf, session-variables, phpmailer, email-attachments

Due to the fact that I have to create a PDF on my server using the uniqid() function, I must subsequently refer to it as a PHP variable in the rest of my code.

The variable that I create for it is a session variable.  I later refer to this session variable in a separate file, which contains my PHPmailer code.  I use the following line to attach the session variable to the mail:

```
$mail->AddStringAttachment($_SESSION[$attachment], "attachment.pdf");
```

The mail is sent correctly with a PDF attached, called attachment.pdf.  However, this attached file, attachment.pdf, is empty.  This is despite the fact that the PDF on the server, which the session variable refers to, contains the complete set of data.  If I attach the name of the PDF, instead of the session variable, it works correctly.

I don't know why the use of a session variable when attaching the PDF is resulting in an empty file being sent.  If anybody may be able to explain why this is happening, or suggest an alternative solution, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `$_SESSION[$attachment]` contains the name of your generated PDF file, so what you are doing here is attaching the *name* of the file as an attachment, rather than the file itself. You should probably be using this instead:

```
$mail->AddAttachment($_SESSION[$attachment], "attachment.pdf");
```